# Как можно запустить firefox через selenium с подключением расширений?

Tags: python, selenium, addons

Подскажите, как можно запустить firefox через selenium с подключением расширений?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477959/selenium-how-to-start-firefox-with-addons

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: Попробовал метод из ссылки, запускается как и запускалось без расширений, пробовал следующее:
`profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`
`profile.add_extension('путь\расширение.xpi')`
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile`

Comment: Вот еще что нашел: https://datarebellion.com/blog/using-firefox-extensions-with-selenium-in-python/

Comment: В гугле я ищу примерно таким запросом: selenium firefox extensions или selenium firefox with extensions

Comment: спасибо, 2ая ссылка помогла!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее решение:

```
ex = "{e58d3966-3d76-4cd9-8552-1582fbc800c1}.xpi"
ex_dir = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\8gslq3cf.default\\extensions\\"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.install_addon(ex_dir + ex, temporary = True)
```